# Why is it difficult to learn a single kernel that performs well at all positions in the convolutional feature map?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am reading Deep Learning book by Ian Goodfellow, in which they wrote (in chapter 9, section 9.5) that:

> " ... MATLAB refers to this as full convolution, in which enough zeros are added for every pixel to be visited k times in each direction, resulting in an output image of width *m + k − 1*. In this case, the output pixels near the border
>   are a function of fewer pixels than the output pixels near the center. This can
>   make it difficult to learn a single kernel that performs well at all positions in
>   the convolutional feature map."

From these lines, I understand that the output pixels near border are a function of fewer input pixels (because of added zero padding) but I do not understand how it becomes difficult to learn a single kernel using **full** convolution